# Is there an algebreic type in lean4?

Tags: lean4

In lean4 I've seen the Real, Rat, and Int types, but is there an Algebreic type?

Loooking at:
https://leanprover-community.github.io/blog/posts/dedekind-domains-and-class-number-in-lean/

which links to

https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/ring_theory/algebraic.html#is_algebraic

It seems that it can be defined as a restriction of the reals, but I was wondering if there was a type representing algebreic numbers that was constructed without reference to the reals.

Comment: "Algebraic type" is ambiguous. In functional programming and proof assistants, there is a notion of [Algebraic Data Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type). What you want is a type of algebraic real numbers. Or at least I assume you want real numbers. If you want all algebraic numbers, you could take the [`algebraic_closure`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/field_theory/is_alg_closed/algebraic_closure.html#algebraic_closure) of $\mathbb{Q}$. Also, I don't quite understand the motivation of your question. In mathlib things are usually only defined one way.

Comment: Do you want a sort of algebraic numbers without specifying an inclusion into the complex numbers? By splitting polynomials one by one?

Comment: Good points. I was looking for an algebric closure of the rationals, so that would have to include non-irrational complex numbers (although I'm mainly concerned with numbers without imaginary components), but I'll look at `algebraic_closure`. My modivation is that I want to assume there is always an algorithm for defining any member of the set. The non-computable reals are something I don't want to deal with. 

WRT to "one way", I've seen multiple ways Pi is defined in mathlib, which is why I thought alternative definitions might be useful or the right way to do some things.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the field structure on `algebraic_closure` uses the axiom of choice and isn't computable. I think `mathlib` (and other Lean libraries) are currently lacking in computable representations of objects. That might change as Lean 4 is also a programming language, but if your motivation is pure constructivism, Lean may not support it to the level you desire. (There are a dozen subtle ways that Lean might sneak `propext` into a proof for example.)  As for $\pi$, what multiple definitions do you mean? (You and I might have a difference of view of what counts as multiple definitions.)

Comment: It is really difficult to study real algebraic numbers in isolation, e.g. there are real algebraic numbers whose radical expression *have to* involve imaginary numbers. I don't think I ever saw a mathematical treatment like that. Do you have a concrete path that you want to follow?

Comment: If your concern is constructivism (in the sense of having some sort of "computable" version of algebraic numbers), algebraic reals are tricky, but doable, you can have a look at Cohen's [Construction of real algebraic numbers in Coq](https://inria.hal.science/hal-00671809). Although this is quite remote from the usual mathlib style, and might require quite some work to adapt, at least the ideas are there.

Comment: Also @JasonRute, I don't think constructivists would consider `propext` as non-constructive. For instance it holds in constructive set theories, or in HoTT (which afaik is considered a constructive setting). Moreover, axioms in `Prop` should not have an impact on computation, because of proof-irrelevance. So if you think constructivism in terms of being able to compute, `propext` should be fine too. Choice is an entirely different matter, of course.

Comment: @MevenLennon-Bertrand Good point, but also I gave Lean 4 too much credit.  It’s easy for `Classical.choice` and `Quot.sound` to also end up in proofs in [surprising](https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/270676-lean4/topic/Clarification.20on.20constructibility/near/385944876) [ways](https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/270676-lean4/topic/Confusing.20axioms.20in.20trivial.20theorem/near/390591263).  Like you said this doesn’t break computability (since this is just used for proofs, including choice which is just used to get LEM I think), but it isn’t constructive either.